# ASP.NET RadioButtonList with custom styled items

Tags: asp.net, radiobuttonlist

I have ASP.NET RadioButtonList, and I need to add a custom styled radiobuttons inside this control: each radiobutton should be inside a div, and with it's own image.

I didn't find any template for ListItem / RadioButton inside RadioButtonList

Is there any way to use a customized ListItem / RadioButton inside RadioButtonList?

With ASP.NET MVC it's very easy, but with ASP.NET Web Forms it looks like a real pain for such a small task. There is no way to use MVC in this task.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I fully understand your requirements but one option may be to write an extension to the base control which implements the additional properties you need.   [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409664/asp-net-server-control-with-an-additional-bindable-field/5409908#5409908) is one where I did this to add bindable “Checked” and “Tooltip” properties to a Check Box List, the technique may apply to your situation as well.

Another alternative might be to use one of the more generic list controls and define your templates to make it look/behave like a Radio Button List.